# HTML-How to alert people of file not available with a tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, http

I recently wrote an api which will serve file to the front.
it looks like this:

```
<a href="donwnloadFile.aspx?file=token" download target="_blank">
```

Download staff works. But the problem is file may sometimes gone and we want the file to be available for only limited time.
I want to make an alert such as "The file you are looking for is not available"
when the files gone or link expired. Is there any way to achieve this through 
http / html markup rather than using ajax call?

Comment: do you want to download file in limit time period after file generated time?

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry for bad wording. The link be valid for limited time. If people click on it adter it expired, There should be  message. But I have no idea how to do tha

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be help full to you

```
[HttpGet]
public String DownloadMyFile() {
    var fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime("file path\\test.pdf");
    var diffInMinit = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(fileCreatedDate)).TotalMinutes;
    if (diffInMinit > 45) {
        //expired
        return "return Expire message";
    } else {
        //return donload link
        return "return donload link";
    }            
}
```